# Saving event in fullcalendar using JQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, fullcalendar

I want to save an event to a database , however i can add the event to the calendar but it does not save to the database and when i try to refresh the page the event disappears.

this is my index page

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
    //changes made start 
   selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    //editable: true,
   select: function (start, end, allDay) {
       var title = prompt('Event Detail:');

        if (title) {
             var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
     var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
     console.log("Event Triggered");
            //start = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        //end = moment(end).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
           // var start =  $.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
           //var end =  $.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");
           //var time = $.formatTime(time, "HH:mm:ss");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'add_event.php',
                data:'title='+ encodeURIComponent(title)+
                   '&start='+ encodeURIComponent(start)+
                   '&end='+ encodeURIComponent(end),
                   //'&url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(json) {
                    alert("Added Successfully");
                  //  alert(json);                   
                  },
              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
            });

            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
            true //make the event stick 
                    );
        } 
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

This is my page for adding the event to the database

```
$data = $_POST;

$json_array["title"]=json_decode($data["title"], true);
$json_array["start"]=json_decode($data["start"], true);
$json_array["end"]=json_decode($data["end"], true);

$title =$json_array["title"];
$start =$json_array["start"];
$end = $json_array["end"];

 require_once "config.php";

try 
 {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,   $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
}
 catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo = null;
```

any help at all would be really appreciated i have looked all over the web for a solution and played around with the code but nothing seems to work.

Comment: how is the log of database?

Comment: how to look to get access to the log of database?

Comment: See the code below: catching the exception will help

Comment: Please don't add an answer where it should be an edit to the question. Use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54022916/edit or the "edit" button under your question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry didnt realise, can you assist in my problem ?

Comment: @TDK i have edited my original question to include your code can you assist me with checking to see if it is correct

Comment: `'events' ('title','start','end')` those should not have quotes `'`, remove them or use ticks `\``. But you don't need them anyway, there is no reserved word or anything that would require them. If this is a JS/Ajax issue, I am not the guy for this.

Comment: @JOHN i have edited the existing answer to be clear

Answer (score 0):

config.php should contain your credentials for example:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";
```

the script for inserting new row in database should be:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$data = $_POST;

$json_array["title"]=json_decode($data["title"], true);
$json_array["start"]=json_decode($data["start"], true);
$json_array["end"]=json_decode($data["end"], true);

$title =$json_array["title"];
$start =$json_array["start"];
$end = $json_array["end"];

require_once "config.php";

try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters

    $sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo = null;
```

Comment: ok so the problem could be in the script that show the database content

Comment: $title =$json_array["title"];
  $start =$json_array["start"];
  $end = $json_array["end"];

require_once "config.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'events' ('title','start','end') VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($title, $start, $end )); - does the problem lie in this code

Comment: This is insert query. I would check the script that read the database (select query)

Comment: $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=paperlesspub', 'root', '');
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT id,title,start,time,end FROM events ";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();  foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["title"],
  'start'   => $row["start"],
  'time'   => $row["time"],
  'end'   => $row["end"]   
 );
}
echo json_encode($data);
this is the select event file

Comment: should i add in the code that you gave me to test into my 'add_event' file ?

Comment: test it in a try catch structure and check the exception catched

Comment: try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, start, end)
VALUES (:title, :start, :end)");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null; - i added in this code but still nothing shows can you offer any advise please

Comment: You see no "New records created successfully" nor Exception ?

Comment: it saves as normal on the calendar but nothing on the database , nor any "New records created successfully" or exceptions

Comment: you said the data is adding to the database.... i'm confused. please be clear, or i can't help

Comment: when i tested your try catch the sample data saved and displayed in the database and calendar however when it took away the hard coded in data and replaced it with the variables im getting from selecting an event date it does not save

Comment: try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, start, end)
VALUES (:title, :start, :end)");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

// insert a row
$title = "sample1";
$start = "2019-01-06";
$end = "2019-01-08";
$stmt->execute();
 - this is the code i tested and it works and saves to the database and displays on the calendar when i load the calendar

Comment: then i replaced the code above with the following code - $json_array["title"]=json_decode($data["title"], true);
  $json_array["start"]=json_decode($data["start"], true);
  $json_array["end"]=json_decode($data["end"], true);
 
  $title =$json_array["title"];
  $start =$json_array["start"];
  $end = $json_array["end"];

Comment: -- continued code -- try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events (title, start, end)
VALUES (:title, :start, :end)");
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

$stmt->execute();

Comment: i hope that clarifies it a bit more please let me know if it does not , thank you for your help so far

Comment: i made the necessary changes you suggested and have edited my original question asked but still nothing is saving to the database

Comment: what's in the console of the browser ?

Comment: Event Triggered event.php:75:10
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/PaperlessPub/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map[Learn More]
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/PaperlessPub/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map[Learn More]

Comment: i have edited your answer to display my code that i have at the moment

Comment: @JOHN new edit at the top of the script, could help in error reporting

Answer (score 0):

So, is the data actually being saved in the database when you add a new event?

If I'm looking at the code, it would seem that you're sending your AJAX call as a POST but putting the data as a GET format, while this may work, it may be better send the data this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay,month'
        },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        minTime: '13:00:00', /* calendar start Timing */
        maxTime: '24:00:00',  /* calendar end Timing */
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        events: "all_events.php",
        displayEventTime: false,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }
        },
        //changes made start 
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        //editable: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Detail:');

            if (title) {
                var dbstart = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
                var dbend = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
                console.log("Event Triggered");
                console.log(dbstart);
                console.log(dbend);
                //start = moment(start).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
                //end = moment(end).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
                // var start =  $.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
                //var end =  $.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");
                //var time = $.formatTime(time, "HH:mm:ss");

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'add_event.php',
                    data: {
                        title: title,
                        start: dbstart,
                        end: dbend
                        //url: url
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status == "success") {
                            alert("Added Successfully");
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: response.title,
                                    start: response.start,
                                    end:   response.end,
                                    allDay: response.allDay
                                },
                                true //make the event stick 
                            );
                        } else {
                            alert("Error occurred. Check Console.");
                            console.log(response.error);
                            //  alert(json);                
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }   
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then, your add_event.php would have:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end   = $_POST['end'];

require_once "config.php";

try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,   $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters

    $sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, end) VALUES (:title, :start, :end)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
    $stmt->execute();

    $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $output['status'] = "success";
    $output['insert_id'] = $id;
    $output['title'] = $title;
    $output['start'] = $start;
    $output['end'] = $end;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // had errors
    $errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
    $output['status'] = "error";
    $output['error'] = $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo = null;

echo json_encode($output);
```

This provides some output back to your page so you can see what's getting passed into the script and used to input into the database.  I also updated your Ajax call to only update the calendar when there's a successful input into the DB and to use the values coming back from the function for better validation.

In production, some of the error outputting should be removed, however.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186141/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-d-wolinski-saving-event-in-fullcalendar-using-jquer).